# Using ROS for Biped motion planning

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bought a 60cm humanoid robot with RC-Servos. I'm already able to drive all servos with ROS. Are there ROS packages for BIPED motion planning available?
Also the question arose, if URBI might have advanatages compared to ROS for a biped?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119346/using-ros-for-biped-motion-planning/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-01-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With [hrpsys](http://wiki.ros.org/hrpsys), some biped robots, `HRP2` and `Atlas` (simulation only afaik) are already capable of planning using [MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/). @Kei Okada can provide more correct info.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-01-19**:
Thanks a lot for your fast answer!

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-01-26**:
I can't find any documentation for hrpsys, is there any available?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-01-26**:
@jonny-j I just added [documentation section](http://wiki.ros.org/hrpsys#Documentation). Basically hrpsys is completely missing user doc to date, and interest like yours helps the maintainers to take action :)

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-01-30**:
Wow, thanks a lot! I have to take some time to look at it deeper :-)!